# Spring Integration aggregator memory leak

Tags: spring, memory-leaks, spring-integration

We have a small spring-integration channel system and which introduce a memory leak on high load on the application. We created this sample application solely to test the spring aggregator.

[SI Applicatiton Sample Git Project](https://github.com/KRVPerera/SpringAggregatorTest)

[Heap Dumps on both scenarios](https://github.com/KRVPerera/HeapDumps)

In **Messenger** class we control the amount of time which the submission thread sleeps after 1000 messages passed to a channel before it stars submitting next 1000.

```
    public void run() {
    int correlationId = 0;
    while (true) {

        for (int sequenceNumber = 0; sequenceNumber < sequenceSize; sequenceNumber++) {
            Job jp = new Job(name);
            Message<Job> message2 = MessageBuilder.withPayload(jp)
           .setSequenceNumber(sequenceNumber)
           .setSequenceSize(sequenceSize)
           .setCorrelationId(correlationId).build();

           channel.send(message2);
        }

        try {
            Thread.sleep(100, 0);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        correlationId++;
        if (correlationId >= CORRELATION_ID_MAX) {
            correlationId = 0;
        }
    }
```

We believe that in normal operation when it does not hog the memory **TreeMap$Entry** takes lot of heap memory having lot of instances, but when reduce sleep time to a very low amount **HashMap$Node** starts to become a issue

**When low load no memory leak**
[image: When low load no memory leak]

**When high load memory leak**
[image: When high load memory leak]

**HashMap$Node** will keep increase its memory utilization forever.

We are printing the list items delay at the terminal from channel **messageOutChannel** after receiving aggregated message list from the aggregator.

```
Time :   647 ms  List size : 1000   Hash : 875023460    By thread : th0  -FP
```

On memory leak situation **Time** will keep increasing and when not in a memory leak situation it will become stable around a number.

Hope someone can shed some light on this and show what we are doing wrong here ?
Thank you

Comment: Use a different `MessageStore` by default all messages are kept in memory until aggregation is complete. With a lot of messages you probably don't want this. By default the `SimpleMessageStore` is used which uses a `Map` to store the messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with the aggregator; the memory "leak" is simply because you are queuing up gazillions of tasks in the task executor and you have no limit on its queue size.

[image]